# Is there a way to automate harvesting cobblestone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been working on a cobblestone generator. Being ultra-lazy, I don't want to spend countless minutes (and who knows how many pickaxes!) actually harvesting the cobblestone. Is there something I can add to the system that will "pop" the cobblestones so I need just run them over and pick them up?

[image: Cobblestone generator]

Comment: If only there were creeper spawners, you could probably work out some system with explosion-proof obsidian walls and precarious creeper taunting.

Comment: What happens if an upside down sticky piston lifts a block off the ground and a non-sticky piston pushes it horizontally off the piston?  Will it fall, or will it pop off?

Comment: @DaveMcClelland It will hover in the air where it was pushed to.

Comment: @StrixVaria Oh, right.  I've been out of minecraft so long I forgot that it treats gravity as an afterthought

Comment: @DaveMcClelland not for Sand and Gravel (and primed TNT!)

Comment: If you do not mind using mods (And Id actually recommend giving this one a try), Better Than Wolves has a Block Dispenser and a Detector block that can be made to automatically pick up the cobblestone as it is being made. You can find some youtube videos but they are a bit dated.

Comment: If you're going down the mod route then something client-side that just lets you do '/item cobblestone 64' would be easier.

Comment: I have a full chest of cobblestone that I don't know what to do with. It came from branch mining for Iron, Diamond, etc.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is an oh-so-basic "proof of concept video". It's a two-level cobble generator which pushes the cobble into a obsidian/water "hopper" which then has TNT dropped on it. The TNT detonates, and the water pushes the harvest cobble to the end of the water tray. Not terribly effiecnt, but still an interesting idea. Large amounts of obsidian is reccomended to protect the rest of the structure from the TNT blast. As for automatically re-loading the TNT hopper, well...

Comment: Bravo, excellent effort.

Comment: Now all I need is a gunpowder harvester and I'll be all set.

Comment: A reloader could load up to 30+ tnt, but I'm not so sure for high cobble amounts, especially since 4 is fairly inefficient

Comment: Can you build in more cobblestone generators, possibly 2 streams coming from each of 4 directions, and the water collector going below the construction instead?

Comment: @fredley you obviously could; as tom mentioned, this is just a [proof-of-concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept), not a 'finished' product.

Comment: When I get home from work, I'll see about making a higher-capacity, more efficent model. I did wonder about using pistons to mash two blocks together but that doesn't work with the Minecraft pistons.

Comment: Bounty on its way...

Answer (score 8):

I believe the only thing that automatically dislodges (or "pops") cobblestone is an explosion. This leaves you with two options:

- Use [pistons](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Piston) to push [TNT](https://minecraft.wiki/w/TNT) into a position where its explosion will only affect the generated cobblestone. This can be done using specifically-placed [obsidian](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Obsidian) to focus the explosion, with a [redstone signal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_circuits) sent through the obsidian (as to not destroy the circuitry). The drawbacks of this method include limited resources to craft the TNT (mostly the [gunpowder](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Gunpowder)) and the finite number of TNT blocks which must be pre-placed into the mechanism.
- Create a system where [mobs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mobs) spawn in a dark room near you, drawing the attention of [creepers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Creeper) and utilizing the explosion (as in StrixVaria's comment). This would require obsidian to focus and contain the explosion, plus a way for creepers to see you and trigger. If designed correctly, the creepers could continuously spawn, and their explosions would kill any other spawned mobs - allowing a continuous, unregulated displacement mechanism. The drawbacks of this method lie in the random nature of mob creation and behavior. The explosion could come from a number of angles, and other mobs might not wander close enough to be destroyed by the creepers. It could also take a very long time for creepers, specifically, to spawn in your room.

Your best bet is probably to harvest as much gunpowder as possible, craft TNT, and then load it into a machine which generates cobblestone in several columns around the TNT. That way, you receive a maximum return for each explosion, and don't have to deal with the randomness of creepers or the rules dictating the spawning of mobs. Use [water](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Water) to wash the popped cobblestone into a designated area, and obsidian to protect your redstone circuitry.

Comment: I will bounty 100 rep to the first person who answers this question with a video of this TNT contraption in operation!

Comment: Upon testing, a disappointingly large percentage of blocks are destroyed, rather than broken.  Only about 1 in 10 blocks survived each explosion.  Given TNT's range, that's about 2-3 blocks per TNT block.  Not very cost-effective.

Comment: It works! (so +1) Requires periodic TNT reloading and a *lot* of space, but it works! Now, to see about that video......

Answer (score 3):

Well, I went back to revise my own design, but it seems Sethbling (YouTube MineBlogger) has already beat me to it. I think this is probably the best thing you're going to get. Still needs a large amount of TNT though.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this video online; it dates back to version 1.5 (before pistons were officially introduced.) I'll see if I can't get something similar working with 1.8.1 unmodified.

Comment: I don't think "Official" miceraft pistions have the ability to smash blocks apart...I may be wrong, I will try it shortly when I do attempt 2 of my proof-of-concept.

Comment: Initial tests don't look promising... I see the block just shuffling back and forth between the two pistons.

Comment: As far as I know, only the mod pistons have the ability to "pop" blocks, and the official pistons never do.

Answer (score 0):

You can "aim" a diamond pick at the spot where the cobblestone is generated, then leave something holding your mouse down (or use an autohotkey script). That's pretty much the only way that cobblestone will "pop".

Comment: -1 Its not the only way! And it says he doesnt want to use pickaxes. Besides, that would also probably destroy the floor, unless generation is instant.

Comment: To fireDude67, you also can just put obsidian at the block you would be looking at when holding the mouse button down to prevent destroying the floor. But that method would really waste alot of pickaxes

Answer (score 0):

This one is the simplest with water and just lava and when they combine you get cobblestone's infinite supply